# ExtJs sortable elements list

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drag-and-drop, extjs, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there any implementation of sortable list in ExtJs as JQuery UI .sortable has ?
Or how could I drop element using jQuery UI sortbale from eastern panel of ExtJs layout to droppable sortable element in central panel of layout ? Now dragging element hides under layout :(

Answer (score 0):

The simplest ExtJS example that's close to a sortable list is this [reorderable toolbars](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.1/examples/toolbar/reorderable.html example.

Next up, there's an example of [drag-and-drop between trees](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.1/examples/tree/custom-drop-logic.html), which can probably be easily modified to simulate a list.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than combining two separate libraries, you may want to look at the Sortable user extension for Ext

http://extjs.com/learn/Extension:Sortable

Comment: That link has long been dead.